# Xamarin click event to page background

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to create a click event that is trigged when the background of the page (Main page) is clicked/tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, you need to add a tap event to the layout (Stack layout in my case)
More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap